# How to add attachment in views slideshow

Tags: views

Goal: Putting text as an attachment on views slideshow

Theme: Bootstrap

Drupal: 8

Content type: Slideshow which has two fields: image and text

Added two nodes of the content type.

Created a slideshow block using views and bootstrap carousel. Slideshow is working just fine. Slideshow just displays the image/slide field.

Below shows just the views block for slideshow.

[image]

Now, I like to put the text field as an attachment (putting the text on top of image in the slideshow) to the views block.

Views > Add > attachment > after that I am lost. I am not sure what setting to use to put the corresponding text field on each image slide.

Below shows I added the attachment in view but when I visit my site, I only see image slideshow and I do not see the text (slide-img) on the slideshow as an attachment.

[image]

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to add your text field to the "Fields" section of this view. Not as an attachment. As a field.

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thanks. One question. In D7, once I add the fields, I am able to see the fields in views slideshow. In D8, just adding the fields do not work. In addition, I also have to click settings > select both fields in the drop down in the bottom of screen > save and then I see these fields in slideshow. Is it a new feature in D8?

Comment: @learn4ever – Not one that I know of. But maybe this triggers some cache being rebuild?